# Dungeons and Dragons god symbols in real life crafts

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, religions-and-deities, intellectual-property

I understand that the D&D deities of the multiverse and various setting pantheons are protected by copyright laws, as are official artworks, but is there anything prohibiting a hobbyist from drawing their own concept of a god's described symbol for a stencil to use on, say, a coaster, and then offer the item for sale someplace like etsy or a local fair?

Answer (score 0):

According to the lawyer in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/9hp409oQD7s), starting around the 14 minute mark, you can probably do this if:

- You only sell or give the product to friends and family, or
- Your product is significantly distinct from the original copyrighted image.

Otherwise, you are likely to face legal repercussions. In the case of selling on etsy or fairs, you would obviously need to go with the second point, and make your work enough different than the original image that it couldn't be called the same.

He is specifically addressing sports teams logos, but talks about copyrighted works in general. Please also listen to his disclaimer at the beginning (only licensed in Ohio and California, verify with a lawyer in your state).